# Mirantis Fuel KVM migration causing DNS to fail

Tags: domain-name-system, openstack, dnsmasq

Has anyone had experience migrating a KVM based Fuel installation?

I copied the .qcow2 disk image to the new host, did a virsh dumpxml, and defined the domain on the new host. That part works flawlessly.

Fuel comes up and everything works fine except DNS resolution to nodes, it looks like whatever fuel is using as a DNS server is not working.

nslookup will not resolve node names, it hits 8.8.8.8 (which means it has failed to use itself as a lookup)

What is the service that fuel uses for its DNS to its nodes? That looks like it has been corrupted somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a simple fix, after clearing the Fuel VM's ARP table and restarting the dnsmasq service, the DNS names resolve correctly now.